# where do we find XMPP framework for iphone?

Tags: iphone, xmpp, xmppframework

I want to develop an chat application, in which I successfully added files of DDXML, DDXMLElement, DXMLElementAddition etc., now I need to add XMPP framework files and its libraries, where do i find these files, is there any open source of these files?

I checked the site  http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/iPhone in which they mentioned which files to be added, but I didnt find those files to include in my project,
if anyone knows please tell me..

Thans in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the XMPP sources?
Here they are:

http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/checkout

You have to checkout the sources manually, that is the easiest way, or you browse the repository and save all files:

http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/browse/

Other libs are described. AsyncSocket is this one:

http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/source/checkout

Answer (score 3):

I think the google repo is officially moved to git at https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

Answer (score 0):

Here are their files for the project:
http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/browse/?r=default#hg%2FXcode%2FiPhoneXMPP

And in your XCode project the framework you need to add is CFNetwork

So right click on your Frameworks folder in XCode

Add > Existing Frameworks > Select "CFNetwork"

and everything should be ready to run their iPhone XMPP example.